# How to redirect Strapi admin panel. (DigitalOcean Strapi)

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, strapi

I have installed DigitalOcean Strapi and the `ip/admin` used to open admin panel. But after I set up a domain and protect it by SSL. All the endpoints are working under `https` but admin panel still is serving under `http` and blocked due to mixed content. Can someone help me how to change strapi's conf ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `url` key in the `./config/server.js` and rebuild the admin for that change to take effect. The admin panel is not rebuild dynamically and a manual build has to be triggered. The `url` key in that config files tells the admin how to contact the Strapi backend.

Comment: `/srv/strapi/strapi-development` then inside `vi .env` changing the `NGINX_URL` and `npm run build` fixed it. Thanks @Derrick.